# Django filter with many fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to filter object and get result if at least one field contains this name.

models.py:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

I tried this one but it doesn't work.

views.py:

```
search_filter_kw = {}
item_name = request.GET.get("searchitemname", '')

if item_name != '':
            search_filter_kw['Q(name__contains) | Q(seller__name__contains)'] = item_name
```

Comment: Try `Q(name__contains=item) | Q(seller_name__contains=item)`.

Comment: @KlausD with dictionary how can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
Item.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=item_name) | Q(seller__name__icontains=item_name))
```

Comment: Damn you beat me to it! :)

Comment: But i want to perform this with my dictionary because i have another dropdowns and inputs in my search, How can i do this with my example?

Comment: @I.Jokhadze Oops, I thought you need a simpler version of it. To implement OR with Q objects and potentially empty values, things get more complicated than my option. Try to look at this https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1700/